# How to remove "New" button from lookup field in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have added a lookup field in MS CRM form. I want to remove "New" button from the lookup.
[image]

I have tried almost all the solutions but not able to resolve it. I am using CRM 2013 version.
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 5):

To remove the `New` button you need to remove the `Create` privilege for entity.
This will affect the possibility to create records in all CRM.

If you want to remove just the `New` button from the inside lookup, you need to use unsupported JavaScript modification.

Comment: I tried unsupported JavaScript modifications. Although it is not working.

Comment: they are called unsupported for a reason

Comment: You can remove the Create privilege as Guido says. If you need that users create records in other bussiness case then make logic that implements a process or a plug-in and use impersonalization. It is maybe better than unsupported js.

Comment: I managed to remove the inline new button from the lookup using unsupported way. However can you tell me please if there any supported/unsupported way to remove the New button from the lookup dialog that appears after clicking "Look Up More Records", that opens in an iframe? (other than using security role)